# Capturing Ansible errors with Fabric

Tags: python, ansible, fabric

How can I capture when a task in an `ansible` playbook fails hence the run fails too?

I'm using `fabric` to wrap the `ansible-playbook` command and this is what I'm currently using.

```
command = local(
    "sudo ansible-playbook %s --extra-vars \"project=%s role=%s env=%s version=%s enterprise=%s\""
    "  --private-key ../inventory/keys/%s" %
    (playbook, project, role, environment, version, enterprise, enterprise), capture=True)
if command:
    if command.stderr:
        print(cyan(command.stderr))
    else:
        print(green(command.stdout))
        print(blue("\nConfigured %s [%s] in %s stack" %
                   (project, role, environment)))
else:
    print(red("\nError configuring %s cloudformation resource stack:::: %s"
              % role, command.stderr))
```

As you can see I have the command and I capture the output.
The problem with this is that `command.stderr` only happens when the `ansible-playbook` command fails for example when `ansible` can't connect to the host etc. but not when a `task` in the playbook fails. when that happens my code still thinks the command actually completed successfully.

Examples below; (This is not being captured by command.stderr)

```
TASK [example.cloudformation : Launch cloudformation template] ****************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
    to retry, use: --limit @example_stack_launch.retry
```

I'm guessing this has to do with `ansible callbacks` but don't know how to expose and use them.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to set `stdout_callback=json` in ansible configuration.
In this case all ansible-playbook output will be in machine-readable json format, so you can check it for errors.